# why a <image> tag was changed <img> tag by jquery，in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, google-chrome, svg

I use jquery to control SVG files in chrome,

```
$('svg #lotsofimage').append("<image xlink:href='" + conf[thing].base + "' width= '" + conf[thing].width + "px' height= '" + conf[thing].height + "px' x='" + thing_x + "pt' y='" + thing_y + "pt' ></image>");
```

but I open the development tools , it displayed like :

```
<img xlink:href="xxxx" width="xxxx">
<image></image>was instead of <img />
```

How to deal with that?

Comment: Ok so I checked. There is no `<image>` tag. What are you upto?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: `image` is part of SVG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not jQuery; it's Chrome's implementation of the DOM. Try this:

```
> document.createElement('image').tagName
'IMG'
```

Out of Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, it seems only Chrome does this. I can't find any reference to this behavior in a few standards I checked. If you want Chrome to create an `image` tag, you might need to put it in the right namespace explicitly using `document.createElementNS`. I don't know how you'd get jQuery to do that.

Comment: Just to insure I have not lost my mind. Since when is there an `<image>` tag?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: It's part of SVG; it doesn't exist in HTML. I was just demonstrating that if you try to create one even without using jQuery, Chrome will turn it into an `img` tag.